# Audit of all user-initiated activity within a Snyk org/group

Tags: audit, audit-trail, snyk

**Task**: Perform audit of all user-initiated activity within a Snyk org/group

**Steps that I followed**:
I referred this document: https://docs.snyk.io/snyk-admin/manage-users-in-organizations-and-groups/retrieve-audit-logs-of-user-initiated-activity-by-api-for-an-org-or-group and tried below cURL commands but encountered errors like `bad API request`, `snyk-openapi-004-not-found`, `group not found`, `An unknown error was encountered while handling your request` with 400|500 errors.

```bash
GROUP_ID=xxxxxxxxxx
SNYK_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxx

curl \
-X 'GET' \
-H "Authorization: Token $SNYK_TOKEN" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://api.snyk.io/rest/groups/${GROUP_ID}/audit_logs/search?version=2023-05-02%7Ebeta"
```

```bash
curl \
-X GET \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: token $SNYK_TOKEN" \
--data-binary \
"{\"filters\": {}}" \
"https://api.snyk.io/v1/group/${GROUP_ID}/audit"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: First cURL command in my above is working now

```bash
GROUP_ID=xxxxxxxxxx
SNYK_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxx

curl \
-X 'GET' \
-H "Authorization: Token $SNYK_TOKEN" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://api.snyk.io/rest/groups/${GROUP_ID}/audit_logs/search?version=2023-05-02%7Ebeta"
```

---

Synk support confirmed that

> We used to have an incident on our end, in regards to this specific endpoint and now the fix has been deployed.
> Can you, please, give it another try and let me know if you still see any issues?